# R - create matrix with values based on the relationship between values in multiple columns of another data frame

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
df <- data.frame(first = c('response','new','NA','early','archive','archive','early','dormant','dormant','response'),
                second = c('response','NA','new','response','response','NA','response','new','dormant','dormant'),
                 third = c('dormant','response','early','response','NA','archive','response','archive','new','new'),
                fourth = c('dormant','NA','archive','early','new','archive','NA','new','early','response'),
                 fifth = c('archive','archive','NA','new','new','response','dormant','new','new','dormant'),
                 sixth = c('response','response','new','archive','NA','early','new','dormant','NA','dormant'),
                seventh = c('new','NA','archive','new','dormant','dormant','NA','NA','NA','new'))
```

Which looks like this:

```
      first   second    third   fourth    fifth    sixth seventh
1  response response  dormant  dormant  archive response     new
2       new       NA response       NA  archive response      NA
3        NA      new    early  archive       NA      new archive
4     early response response    early      new  archive     new
5   archive response       NA      new      new       NA dormant
6   archive       NA  archive  archive response    early dormant
7     early response response       NA  dormant      new      NA
8   dormant      new  archive      new      new  dormant      NA
9   dormant  dormant      new    early      new       NA      NA
10 response  dormant      new response  dormant  dormant     new
```

I need to return a matrix which shows 1 or 0 based on the relationship between a column and the previous column considering certain conditions.

The matrix must contain the value 1 when a column contains any of 'response','new' or 'early' *and* the previous column contains anything *other than* 'response','new' or 'early', and return 0 otherwise.

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
   first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh
1      0      0     0      0     0     1       0
2      0      0     1      0     0     1       0
3      0      1     0      0     0     1       0
4      0      0     0      0     0     0       1
5      0      1     0      1     0     0       0
6      0      0     0      0     1     0       0
7      0      0     0      0     0     1       0
8      0      1     0      1     0     0       0
9      0      0     1      0     0     0       0
10     0      0     1      0     0     0       1
```

I would expect the first column to only contain 0 as there is no previous column to compare to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 = replace(df, is.na(df), "NA_chr")
m = Reduce("|", lapply(c("response", "new", "early"), function(x) df2[,-1] == x)) * 
    Reduce("&", lapply(c("response", "new", "early"), function(x) df2[,-NCOL(df)] != x))
m = cbind(rep(0, NROW(m)), m)
m
#        second third fourth fifth sixth seventh
# [1,] 0      0     0      0     0     1       0
# [2,] 0      0     1      0     0     1       0
# [3,] 0      1     0      0     0     1       0
# [4,] 0      0     0      0     0     0       1
# [5,] 0      1     0      1     0     0       0
# [6,] 0      0     0      0     1     0       0
# [7,] 0      0     0      0     0     1       0
# [8,] 0      1     0      1     0     0       0
# [9,] 0      0     1      0     0     0       0
#[10,] 0      0     1      0     0     0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `purrr package`:

```
library(purrr)

items <- c("response", "new", "early")

map2_dfc(df[,2:ncol(df)],df[,1:(ncol(df) - 1)], function(x,y){
    as.numeric((x%in% items) & !(y %in% items))
})
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   second third fourth fifth sixth seventh
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1      0     0      0     0     1       0
 2      0     1      0     0     1       0
 3      1     0      0     0     1       0
 4      0     0      0     0     0       1
 5      1     0      1     0     0       0
 6      0     0      0     1     0       0
 7      0     0      0     0     1       0
 8      1     0      1     0     0       0
 9      0     1      0     0     0       0
10      0     1      0     0     0       1
```